# D3: condition to find nodes without edges in force directed graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using a dynamic force directed graph with a set of nodes. Its links change with the changes made to a slider. When the graph is created,I want to remove all the nodes from the graph that do not have any links to them for that slider value.

How do you check if the nodes have a link connect to them?

Comment: You could iterate through the list of links, collect the source and target nodes and check which nodes in the nodes list don't appear there.

Comment: Hi thanks. I tried that, but cant delete the nodes.
     for (var i = 0; i<=all_nodes.length; i++){
                    if (node_with_link.indexOf(all_nodes[i])==-1){
                        nodesToDelete.push(all_nodes[i]);
                        node.splice(all_nodes[i]);
                    }
                }
This removes all nodes. How do I remove the nodes without the links?

Comment: As I've said, you could try to iterate over the list of links. I have no idea what the variables in your code fragement are, so I can't tell you why it doesn't work.